# How to fetch google maps data and show in the app

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I want to show all available restaurants on google to my flutter app and user can done a booking or can call to the restaurant
so i just wanna know how we can use google data in our app i have no idea on this

Comment: Have a look on [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

Comment: Please check the [`google_maps_webservice`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice) flutter package that includes the Places API - [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) from Google Maps APIs which used to search for nearby places like restaurants.